# Is $H^*($vanishing cycles$)$ computed by the twisted de Rham complex?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, vanishing-cycles

In notes by [Sabbah](https://perso.pages.math.cnrs.fr/users/claude.sabbah/livres/sabbah_chicago1205.pdf) (Theorem 3), it is stated that the cohomology
$$\text{H}^*(X,\varphi_f)$$
of the vanishing cycle sheaf of a function $f:X\to \mathbf{A}^1$ for certain $X$ is expected to be the same as something like the cohomology of the twisted de Rham complex
$$\text{H}^*\left(X\times\mathbf{A}^1,(\Omega_{X}^*\boxtimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{A}^1},d\otimes\text{id}+\wedge df\otimes z)\right).$$
See Theorem 3 for the precise statement.

**My question:** Why heuristically might you expect this to be true, starting with the usual definition of $\varphi_f$ as in [Illusie's notes](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Eluc.illusie/vanishing1b.pdf)?* Has some version of the above conjecture been proven, and if so what is it?

---

*I'm looking for a more precise heuristic than both sides having to do with  sheaf cohomology and the critical locus of $f$.

Comment: A more detailed account giving a better answer is in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0436.pdf